# Add an additional legend according to the colors of x axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have modified the colors of my x axis labels according to their group.
For that, I have used the following pseudocode:

```
library(ggsci)
library(ggplot2)
x_cols = pal_jco()(length(unique(melted_df$Group)))
names(x_cols) = unique(melted_df$Group)
ggplot(melted_df, ... + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = x_cols))
```

I would like to add a legend to the plot (if possible, outside the plot), that explains the colouring of the x axis labels.

`melted_df` dataframe looks like this:
[image]

Here the full code:

```
#Generate color mapping
x_cols = pal_jco()(length(unique(melted_df$Group)))
names(x_cols) = unique(melted_df$Group)
melted_df$mycolors = sapply(as.character(melted_df$Group), function(x) x_cols[x])

#Plot
ggplot(melted_df, aes(fill=variable, y=value, x=fct_inorder(id))) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Barplot") +
   theme_bw() +
   xlab("samples") + ylab("Counts") +
   theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=10), axis.title.x=element_text(size=10),
        plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = (15), hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(distinct(samples_melt[c("id", "mycolors")])$mycolors)) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Columns"))
```

Comment: Can you show the actual data and code you used? The snippet you have included isn't reproducible (or even syntactically complete)

Comment: The actual data is sensitive unfortunately. I can try to create a dummy example. I was hoping to have an easy answer to "how to add an additional legend that explains the colors in the x axis text", but maybe it is not that easy.

Comment: @AllanCameron I tried to generate a dummy example quickly. I also saw your answer, is it possible to not override the legend? I would like to keep the actual legend that explains the bar colors of the stacked barplot.

Comment: Sure, see my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addressed the issue using `Legend()` constructor, provided by [ComplexHeatmap](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap) library.

I first used the code provided above under the **EDIT** section, and then I added the following code in order to draw an additional legend explaining the x-axis colouring.

```
lgd = Legend(labels = names(x_cols), title = "Group", labels_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8), nrow = 1, legend_gp = gpar(fill = x_cols))
draw(lgd, x = unit(1.8, "cm"), y = unit(0.3, "cm"), just = c("left", "bottom"))
```

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of a reproducible example, here is how you might do it with the built-in `iris` data set:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "col", aes(fill = Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species), alpha = 0, key_glyph = draw_key_text) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  labs(color = "") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1, size = 8))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = scales::hue_pal()(3), face = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I don't manage to make it work for my specific plot though(using the code I posted in the Edit).